# Add one image over the front and back of my booklet?

Tags: pdftex, booklet

I have created a booklet with `\usepackage[print,1to1]{booklet}`.

I have one large image I'd like to use for the cover, so by book, stapled, would be:

1. right side of cover image
2. blank (inside of front cover)
3. content page 1
4. content page 2
5. content page 3
6. content page 4
7. blank (inside of back cover)
8. left side of cover image

Unstapled, the pdf would be

```
page 1: the complete cover image
Left of cover image | right of cover image

page 2:
blank               | blank

page 3:
content 4           | content 1

page 4:
content 2           | content 3
```

Here's the code I would use *if* I had separate front and back cover images

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{memoir}

\usepackage[print,1to1]{booklet}

\begin{document}

right side of cover image
\newpage
(blank)
\newpage
content 1
\newpage
content 2
\newpage
content 3
\newpage
content 4
\newpage
(blank)
\newpage
left side of cover image

\end{document}
```

This is straightforward enough with a pdf editor, but I am creating multiple such booklets and assume there is an easier way.

Comment: Normally covers are printed on oversized paper then cut to size.  Physical printers cannot go all the way to the edges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This formats the text and splits the cover image.  I switched to a4paper to avoid gaps on the cover.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newsavebox{\mycover}% scaling and cropping are easier when done separately
\savebox{\mycover}{\includegraphics[width=2\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{example-image}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
  \clip (current page.south west) rectangle (current page.north east);% just to be safe
  \path (current page.west) node[inner sep=0pt]{\usebox\mycover};
\end{tikzpicture}%
\cleardoublepage
\setcounter{page}{1}
\lipsum[1-16]
\newpage\thispagestyle{empty}\null\newpage\thispagestyle{empty}%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
  \clip (current page.south west) rectangle (current page.north east);% just to be safe
  \path (current page.east) node[inner sep=0pt]{\usebox\mycover};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

And this formats it (stored as test6.pdf) as a booklet.  Assumes paper feeds through printer in portrait (alternate pages are inverted).

```
\documentclass[a4paper,landscape]{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\begin{document}
\includepdf[pages=-,nup=2x1,booklet]{test6}
\end{document}
```

Comment: If tdont need the overlay fetaure, yoy cousl avoid the use of the large pgf/tikz package by simply using includegraphics/ includepdf  with cropping on both pages, in some sense like in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/423371)

Use `\includepdf[pages=1,trim=xx yy zz aa, clip=true, height=\paperheight,width=\paperwidth]{image}`, where `xx yy zz aa` define  the amout of space to be removed from `image`

Comment: You are right, there are many ways to do it.  I try to avoid scaling and cropping in the same step, but \adjustbox also works.  You can use newgeometry to change the margins, or just use negative \vspace and \hspace.  The main reason for using TikZ was opacity.